# Mapping Tfs Directory To More than one Local workspace

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am very new to TFS.

Is it possible to Map same TFS Directory to 2 local workspaces.? If yes, How.?

i have some changes in my local workspace files. But do not want to check in all those changes for now, but few changes needs to be checked in.

Please help.

Comment: You want to shelve the changes, you can revert your workspace back to the original files then.  Once you're ready to commit the original changes, you simply "unshelve" the changes.

Comment: Any update on this, Sahi?

Answer (score 1):

One workspace does not allow the same TFS folder to be mapped to more
 than one local directory.

> However, you can have two or more workspaces for one computer, and **each
>   workspace can map a TFS folder to a different local folder.** What
>   revisions of files are in each workspace is tracked separately (to
>   keep each up to date you need to do a get in each: easy with ['tf
>   get'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the command line).

But in your case, you don't have to create multiple workspaces, just use shelvesets as comment suggested. You could simply [**suspend your work and manage your shelvesets**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets), shelve the changes which you not want to check in, just check in the ones you need.

Once you checked in, just Unshelve changes and it will retrieve the changes in the shelveset into your workspace, you could continue work on it. More details please refer the tutorial above.

Just be careful,  unlike a changeset, a shelveset is a **non-versioned entity**.